# Taylor's theorem for multi variable function, purpose of $t?$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, multiple-integral

In Nocedal and Wright's book on Numerical Optimization. On page 14 we have theorem 2.1 - Taylors theorem, equation 2.6 which is, I think an approximation for a multi variable function f which is supposed to be twice continuously differentiable.

[image]

From the answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424576/expression-for-the-gradient-using-taylors-theorem/2450534#2450534) I understand how 2.4 and 2.5 was derived. But I don't see how we can get 2.6. It looks like 2.5 was integrated to get 2.6 but  it's not clear what the limits would be. Also I think it should be an approximation there in 2.6 since it's only the taylor's expansion to 2nd order terms.

if $p$ was a vector of small magnitude, to cause a perturbation around $x_o$ for the function $f$, I'd imagine the equation should look like this,

[image: my ans]

So instead of $x+tp$ in the 3rd term, I would expect just $x$. Also if it's an equality sign between LHS and RHS, I would need to mention the extra terms of 3rd order and beyond.

So is 2.6 correct, if it is how can I derive it?

Comment: Note that these are not approximations, they are equalities. So there are no "leftover small terms". The tradeoff is that the third term involves evaluating $f$ at a point which is probably different from $x$.

Comment: Yeah they evaluate f at $x+tp$ for "some" t, which I think means that you can find a t for which the equality is satisfied?

Comment: Yes, precisely. It’s an existence statement.

Answer (score 2):

By the Taylor approximation in one dimension we have for every $C^2$-function $\gamma:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ and every $t_0,t\in\Bbb R$
$$\gamma(t)=\gamma(t_0)+\gamma'(t_0)(t-t_0)+R_1(t)$$
for some remainder $R_1(t)$ with $\lim_{t\to t_0}\frac{R_1(t)}{t-t_0}=0$. The remainder can be expressed in the Lagrange form which gives
$$\gamma(t)=\gamma(t_0)+\gamma'(t_0)(t-t_0)+\frac12\gamma''(\xi)(t-t_0)^2$$
for some $\xi$ between $t$ and $t_0$. Choosing $t_0=0$, $t=1$ and $\gamma(t):=f(x+tp)$ we thus have
$$\gamma(1)=\gamma(0)+\gamma'(0)+\frac12\gamma''(\xi)$$
for some $\xi\in]0,1[$. But this is exactly
$$f(x+p)=f(x)+\nabla f(x)^Tp+\frac12 p^T\nabla^2f(x+\xi p)p$$
(since
$$\frac{\gamma(t+s)-\gamma(t)}{s}=\frac{f(x+tp+sp)-f(x+tp)}{s}\to f'(x+tp)(p)=\nabla f(x+tp)^Tp$$
for $s\to 0$ implies that $\gamma'(t)=f(x+tp)^Tp$ and especially $\gamma'(0)=f(x)^Tp$ and similar for the second derivative).